# How can I split the number of user posts in total and by each category in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, pivot

I want to do a query that return the number of posts that the user wrote in total , and the number of posts that he wrote of each category

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT  USERS.username , POST_USERS.post_id , POST_CATEGORIES.category_name 
FROM USERS 
INNER JOIN POST_USERS on USERS.id = POST_USERS.user_ident
INNER JOIN POST_CATEGORIES on POST_USERS.post_id = POST_CATEGORIES.post_id;
```

and the result is:

```
---------+-------------+----------------+---
|username|  post_id    |  category_name    |
---------+-------------+----------------+---
 pepe         77              css
 pepe         77              php
 juan         77              css
 juan         77              php
```

(a post can have multiple categories)

What I want to get is this:

```
---------+--------------+---------------+--------
|username|  total_posts |    css        |  php   |
---------+--------------+---------------+--------
 pepe         5               2             3
 juan         3               1             2
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: i only see 2 posts in category `php`, and your count shows 3 ....

Comment: and please read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) before [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63746432/edit) your post...

Comment: @Luuk , it's just a example not the real results that it would give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. The tables are properly joined, now we need to *pivot* the dataset. Provided that you know in advance the categories list, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    u.username, 
    count(*) total_posts,
    sum(c.category_name = 'css') css,
    sum(c.category_name = 'php') php
from users u
inner join post_users pu      on pu.user_ident = u.id
inner join post_categories pc on pc.post_id = pu.post_id
group by u.id, u.username
```

Comment: it is not a "pivot", `group by` does do aggregation. While, when doing "pivoting" almost always aggregation is being used, aggregation is not the same as pivoting.   (Hard to explain in a language that i do no speak natively )